# Slightly reword the migration notice displayed on inbound questions

Tags: feature-request, migration, wording, migration-notice

I saw the migration notice on a question here, on MSO:

[image]

I couldn't help but think the message could be worded a bit better. "This question *came from*" is a little generic, and might be confusing to newbies... came from, how?

How about "This question *was moved here* from our site for professional and enthusiast programmers"?

Comment: How was the question moved here?

Comment: @random A standard migration. The question itself is irrelevant.

Comment: Are you saying "came from" isn't professional because it alludes to a sexual act?

Comment: @random What?! No.. lol.. that thought genuinely hadn't even occurred to me! :P The wording just sounds "wrong"/"strange".

Comment: **+1** I think the proposed new wording sounds better.